# How to annotate a text on the top of a cropped image using ImageMagick

Tags: linux, bash, image, imagemagick, crop

I want to annotate a counter on the top of a series of images each cropped of an image.
I wrote:

```
crop=1050x"$height"+0+"$top"
loc=90x90+10+"$top"
time=$((time-1))
convert $image -crop "$crop" -pointsize 24 -fill white -undercolor '#00000080' -gravity North -annotate $loc  "$time" "out/page_"$counter"_"$i".png"
```

This is called in a loop and the variable top increases. So, I can see the counter on the top of first output image but not on the rest. It seems it first draws the counter on the original image and then crop it, so the counter disappears after crop.

I tried to use a `$loc` variable for the location of annotation but it also doesn't work!

Comment: I'd add `+repage` right after the `-crop` operation to set the paging geometry back to WxH+0+0. And if you want the annotation the same distance from the top in every image, don't increment that distance with $top in the $loc variable. Just use the number of pixels you want the text to be down from the top.

Comment: @GeeMack thanks, you could post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you "-crop" with ImageMagick you'll often need to add "+repage" right after the operation to set the paging geometry of the cropped piece(s) back to WxH+0+0. This can be important because some operations like "-annotate" will locate according to that geometry.

In your command, if you want the annotation the same distance from the top in every image, repage after the crop, and don't increment that distance with "$top" in the "$loc" variable. Just use the number of pixels you want the text to be down from the top.